# re-creating string with elements separated by commas

Tags: string, stata

I am working with a local macro that looks like:

```
loc str_orig "2000 2015 2019 2020"
```

I would like to achieve the following without using a loop:

```
"2000, 2015, 2019, 2020"
```

Is there a built-in (ideally one-line) command to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the spaces with a comma and a space.

```
local str_orig "2000 2015 2019 2020"

local str_comma : subinstr local str_orig " " ", ", all
```

See also `help extended_fcn` for info on extended macro functions.